# if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then $f$ has a maximum - Proof refutation

Tags: real-analysis

So I adapted this argument from one that assumes **a closed interval**, but I can't see why the arguement fails (even though I think it should) if we're talking about **an open interval**

**Theorem**
*if $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, then $\exists y \in (a,b)$ such that $f(y) \geq f$*

Let $A = \big \{ f(x) : x \in (a, b) \big \}$

$A$ is bounded, and obviously not empty. Hence there exists $\alpha = \text{sup} \ A$

Suppose $\alpha \not \in A$, and therefore $\alpha > f(x)$

Consider $(g \circ f) (x) = \dfrac{1}{\alpha - f(x)}$

We know $\alpha - f(x) \in \mathbb{P}$, therefore $g$ is cts. everywhere

Consider $\alpha - \epsilon < b$. It is certainly not an upper bound, and so there exists $f(x') \in A$ where $f(x') > \alpha - \epsilon$.

\begin{align*}
    &\phantom{\Rightarrow}\alpha - \epsilon < f(x') \\
    &\Rightarrow \alpha - f(x') < \epsilon \\
    &\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} < \frac{1}{\alpha - f(x')} \\
    &\Rightarrow \frac{1}{\epsilon} < (x') && \left (f(x') \in A \right)  \\
    &\Rightarrow N < g(x')
\end{align*}

A contradiction, for $g$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and therefore bounded above.

Comment: What does "cts.@" mean?

Comment: continuous - I'll make the correction

Comment: The function $f(x)=x$  is a counterexample on the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @lulu lol fantastic counterexample.

Comment: @lulu isn't that bounded by anything greater than 1?

Comment: I think the two main problems with your proof: $(1)$ we don't necessarily have $A$ is bounded, but in the case that it *is* bounded, $(2)$ you seem to be using as a fact the thing that you hope to prove (namely, you say $g$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and therefore bounded above...but this is precisely what you are trying to prove).

Comment: @user_hello1 lulu's example shows that your supposed theorem is false:  $f(x)=x$ has neither max nor min on $(0,1)$.

Comment: The problem lulu's counterexample demonstrates is that there is no $y\in(0,1)$ such that $f(y)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: $g$ needs not be bounded on $(a,b)$. In fact, since you've defined it as $-\frac{1}{f(x)-\sup_{y\in (a,b)} f(y)}$, you know that, if it is defined on the whole $(a,b)$, then it is unbounded.

Comment: No, I understand. I am using 'bounded' here to refer to any upper bound.

Comment: To be clear, then, that is not what your "theorem" states; you've specifically stated that there exists a $y\in(a,b)$ such that $f(y)\geq f$.

Comment: @user_hello1  but that's not what "bounded" means.  In the example in my answer it has a lower bound but no upper.  And that's precisely the problem:  your proof uses the sup, which need not exist!

Comment: As I said, the function $f(x)=x$ is a counterexample to your theorem on $(0,1)$.  That is, there is no $y\in (0,1)$ such that $f(y)≥f(x)$ for every $x\in (0,1)$.  If you meant something else, please edit accordingly.  Otherwise, I suggest going through your argument using my function to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Your set $A$ need not be bounded.  For example, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with domain $(0,1)$.  In particular, the resulting set $A$ in this example has no upper bound, so you may not use its supremum as in your argument.